# How to select hasMany relation as a column name

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join, activerecord, query-builder

I have 2 table.

1. movies
2. movie_meta

**movies table**

```
| id | name         |
---------------------
| 1 | Harry Potter  |
| 2 | Joker         |
| 3 | Need For Speed|
```

**movie_meta table**

```
| id | movie_id | key     | value            |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1        | country | USA              |
| 2  | 1        | genre   | Horror & Sci-Fi  |
| 3  | 1        | actor   | Daniel Radcliffe |
```

What I want to achive is like this.

```
| id | name         | country | genre           | actor            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Harry Potter | USA     | Horror & Sci-Fi | Daniel Radcliffe |
```

The movie_meta table is unlimited of rows number. So, how to select ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `movie_meta` three times:

```
select 
    m.*,
    c.value country,
    g.value genre,
    a.value actor
from movie m
inner join movie_meta c on c.movie_id = m.id and c.key = 'country'
inner join movie_meta g on g.movie_id = m.id and g.key = 'genre'
inner join movie_meta a on a.movie_id = m.id and a.key = 'actor'
```

For performance, you want an index on `movie_meta(movie_id, key)`.

If there is a chance that one of the attribute is missing is the meta table, you can turn the `inner join`s to `left join`s.

Or you can do conditional aggregation (this is neater but might be less efficient):

```
select 
    m.id,
    m.name,
    max(case when x.key = 'country' then value end) country,
    max(case when x.key = 'genre' then value end) genre,
    max(case when x.key = 'actor' then value end) actor
from movie m
inner join movie_meta x on x.movie_id = m.id
group by m.id, m.name
```

Comment: How if the movie meta is "n" value ?
So i don't know how much rows it is, but I want to display all the key in as a column

Comment: @AgengD.Prastyawan: a SQL query must return a *fixed* set of columns, so what you want is not possible in standard SQL. You would need to use dynamic SQL (but this is not the question you originally asked).

Answer (score 0):

One method uses conditional aggregation.  Another uses multiple `join`s.  The two are probably similar performance-wise for this example:

```
select m.*, mmc.value as country, mmg.value as genre, mma.value as actor
from movies m left join
     movie_meta mmc
     on mmc.movie_id = m.id = and mmc.key = 'country' left join
     movie_meta mma
     on mma.movie_id = m.id = and mma.key = 'actor' left join
     movie_meta mmg
     on mmg.movie_id = m.id = and mmg.key = 'genre' ;
```

Note that your example has only one actor and genre per movie.  In the real world, both of these could have multiple values.